# Debugging Python Program

Tags: python, debugging, primes

Really can't understand what's going on in this program, it returns

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26, 28, 29, 31, 32, 34, 37, 38, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 49]
```

Help?

```
def primeTest(n):
     if n < 2:
        return False
     if n == 2:
        return True
     for x in range(3, int(n ** 0.5 + 0.5), 2):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
     return True
def primeList(largestValue):
    primes = []
        for a in range(2, largestValue):
            if primeTest(a) == True:
                primes.append(a)
    return primes     
print(primeList(101))
```

I've realised it's the first function `primeTest`, becuase if I input `print(primeTest(10))` it returns `True`.

Comment: You don't actually have a `return` statement in your `primeList`.

Comment: What else shall it return other than True, False or None??? A print() statement at the end of a method *prints* some output but does not return anything! Have you heard of 'return'? If not, read the Python documentation.

Comment: Oh yeah, now I feel really dumb! @Cairnarvon

Comment: But even with the return statement, it returns the wrong numbers?

Comment: If that's really your code, you build a list of primes in the `primeList` function named `primes` but at the end of that function you return the function itself. The print output I'd expect to see is somthing like '<function primeList at 0x44444444>`

Comment: No @bgporter, it definitely returns `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26, 28, 29, 31, 32, 34, 37, 38, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 49]` if I set `largestValue` to `50`

Comment: You're not testing if the number is divisible by two; the loop with the modulus operation starts at three...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some problems that jump out:

1) You never check for divisibility by `2`.

2) `primeList()` should return `primes` and not `primeList`.

3) The upper bound in `range(3, int(n ** 0.5 + 0.5), 2)` is off by one. For example, for `n==9` the divisibility by `3` is never checked.

Once I fix these, the code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

first, you should switch the inner and outer function
then do the prime test correct, and finally return the list, not the function:

```
def primeList(largestValue):
    def isPrime(n):
        if n < 2: return False
        if n == 2: return True
        if n & 1 == 0: return False
        for x in range(3, int(n ** 0.5)+1, 2):
            if n % x == 0:
                return False
        return True


    primes = []
    for a in range(2, largestValue):
        if isPrime(a):
            primes.append(a)
    return primes

print(primeList(101))
```